# 'Bad file descriptor' error on an accepted socket

Tags: c, windows, sockets, networking

I'm trying to get into network programming and have been following a guide on sockets. I wrote a simple Windows TCP server and client in C, but cannot seem to get them working. The second the client connects, the server throws a 'Bad file descriptor' error and closes. I don't understand how the file descriptor that was just created by `accept()` can be bad. I have done research on this and have only found people who had closed the file before reading it, which I did not.

Here is the code :

SERVER

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA WSAData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &WSAData);

    SOCKET sock, newsock;
    int portno, clilen;
    char buffer[256];
    SOCKADDR_IN serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int n;

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (sock < 0)
    {
        perror("Error opening socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset((char *) &serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
    portno = 5001;

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if (bind(sock, (SOCKADDR *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Eror on binding");
        exit(1);
    }

    listen(sock, 5);
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

    newsock = accept(sock, (SOCKADDR *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
    if (newsock < 0)
    {
        perror("Error on accept");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(buffer, 0, 256);
    n = read(newsock, buffer, 255);

    if (n < 0)
    {
        perror("Error reading from socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Here is the message : %s\n", buffer);

    n = write(newsock, "I got your message", 18);
    if (n < 0) 
    {
        perror("Error writing to socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

CLIENT

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA WSAData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &WSAData);

    SOCKET sock;
    int portno, n;
    SOCKADDR_IN serv_addr;
    HOSTENT *server;
    char buffer[256];

    if (argc < 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage : %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }

    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0)
    {
        perror("Error opening socket\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);

    if (server == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error, no such host");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset((char *) &serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    memcpy((char *) &serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, (char *) server->h_addr, server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if (connect(sock, (SOCKADDR *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error connecting to server");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Please enter your message : ");
    memset(buffer, 0, 256);
    fgets(buffer, 255, stdin);

    n = write(sock, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    if (n < 0)
    {
        perror("Error writing to socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(buffer, 0, 256);
    n = read(sock, buffer, 255);

    if (n < 0)
    {
        perror("Error reading from socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

...And here's the output just in case :

```
C:\...myfolder>server
*here it does nothing until I start the client with "client 127.0.0.1 5001" in another window*
Error reading from socket: Bad file descriptor
```

Do you see what is wrong with my code? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would put this in a comment, but try using the [recv()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121(v=vs.85).aspx) function instead of read(). This is because read() doesn't call into the Socket API, so as far as Windows is concerned, the file descriptor isn't valid.

On the same note, in your client you should use [send()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740149%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) instead of write().

Comment: Thank you, it works now! Does this mean that the windows socket API isn't implemented the same way as the linux sockets? As in, are my socket variables really file descriptors or just an identifier specifically made for winsock?

Comment: Is *anything* really a file descriptor on Windows, or is it all just a pile of kludges pretending to be a file descriptor?

Comment: You have a point. But then are all those kludges the same type of kludge? Are `sock` and `stdin` the same type of thing, and if not how do they differ?

Comment: Going back to the time before TCP/IP networking was including with Windows, and winsock was a third-party library, it wasn't possible to integrate these newfangled "socket" objects with the existing system of file handles, so the file descriptors created by winsock functions had no meaning outside the winsock library, which meant you had to use recv and not read. Somehow this situation failed to improve when winsock became part of the OS.